# From a Power Point to a Mathematica Slide Show

Tags: slideshows

I have a lengthy power point slide show I made (very easily) with 'copy and paste' out of a Microsoft Word Document. Can I copy and paste each one of my slides into a Mathematica slide show? Is there some way to copy and paste all of my power point slides into a Mathematica slide show with one fell swoop? My power point templates are garden variety, nothing special. I have no wish to include any interactive manipulates into my Mathematica slide show. Thanks very much.

Comment: Would it work for you to save the Powerpoint as a pdf file and then import as a list of pages into a notebook? That won't have any animations of the Powerpoint, but might be good enough for simple slides.

Comment: I put the power point file (in the pdf format) in the same folder (directory) as my Mathematica notebook. I cannot figure out the correct grammar for: Import[] Keep getting error messages about not being able to find my file.

Comment: Look at the command NotebookDirectory[]

Comment: Sir, you are writing to a blithering idiot. What, where is a command notebook directory?